# Return all results within the month that is 5 months from now in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a MySQL report that could be run at any point in a given month. When run, it will need to pull through all results where the date of the record is in the month in 5 months' time - e.g. if run any time in December, it will need to pull through any records with a date between 1st May and 31st May 2020, if run in January it would pull through the June records and so on.

Have been searching for a few different date functions but can't seem to find the right one to let me look ahead 5 months using a date interval, but that will only show me from the 1st to the last day of that month.

Closest I seem to have is this (which my query doesn't like):

```
due_date <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 6, -1) AND due_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 5, 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query to get that result -

```
SELECT adddate(current_date, interval 5 month) curr_date
      ,DATE_SUB(adddate(current_date, interval 5 month),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(adddate(current_date, interval 5 month))-1 DAY) AS '1st of month'
      ,last_day(adddate(now(), interval 5 month)) last_of_month;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=23982584dbd537786423927df57abc5f) is the fiddle.